# "Pin" a button inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with lots of columns, so there is a big horizontal scroll. Also I have server paging, so I show only first 100 rows. And in order to load more rows, I show a button "Load next 100 rows" inside the grid. The problem, is the button may become invisible, because it will be scrolled out of view. This is bad. I would like to make its horizontal position fixed in the center of scrollviewer view port. Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of what needs to be done]

You see, that horizontal scroll is quite large, and when user uses it, button may become invisible. I show the button on the last row of grid, so when you scroll down you will only see the button when you got to the end.

Actually I already implemented what I wanted, but with quite dirty trick. I listen to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged and in the hanler I update the Margin of the button.

```
private void RulesXamDataGrid_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (XamDataGrid)sender;
    var scroll = grid.FindDescendant<ScrollViewer>();
    var loadMoreButton = grid.FindElement<Button>(x => x.Name == "loadMoreButton").FirstOrDefault();
    if (scroll != null && loadMoreButton != null)
        loadMoreButton.Margin =
            new Thickness(scroll.HorizontalOffset + (scroll.ViewportWidth - loadMoreButton.ActualWidth) / 2, loadMoreButton.Margin.Top, loadMoreButton.Margin.Right, loadMoreButton.Margin.Bottom);
}
```

I don't like the implementation, so if you have better (MVVM way), it would be great.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what it looks like now?  When you say you want the button in the center of the viewport, you mean you want it overlaid on top of the rows?  That seems an odd place to put it.

Answer (score 1):

If when you say Grid you mean DataGrid then you should be able to mark the button with the attached property

```
SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="None"
```

This will mean it will not scroll while everything else should

Another option if this does not work would be to place them both into a containing grid so the button is no longer inside the scrollviewer.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid>

    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Load More" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```